# PHP nested array

Tags: php, arrays

So I've been given this by a tutor of mine, to complete I'm slightly stuck. Ive tired loads of methods but not get the right way of displaying the data.

```
        <?php

        /*
        * Below is an array of cakes and information about them.
        * Please write a script that generates the following html snippet
        *
        *    <ul>
        *      <li>Wedding Cake<br />Flavour: hopes and dreams</li>
        *       <li>Chocolate Gateau<br />Flavour: chocolate</li>
        *       <li>Black Forest Gateau<br />Flavour: fruity</li>
        *       <li>Victoria Sponge<br />Flavour: vanilla</li>
        *       <li>Tottenham Cake<br />Flavour: strawberry</li>
        *    </ul>
        *
        * (html or xhtml <br> / <br /> is fine!)
        * Note that the list is ordered in descending order of price.
        */

        $cakes = array(
        "chocolate_gateau"=>array(
            "flavour"=>"chocolate",
            "price"=>3.50),
        "victoria_sponge"=>array(
            "flavour"=>"vanilla",
            "price"=>1.50),
        "black_forest_gateau"=>array(
            "flavour"=>"fruity",
            "price"=>2.20),
        "tottenham_cake"=>array(
            "flavour"=>"strawberry",
            "price"=>0.58),
        "wedding_cake"=>array(
            "flavour"=>"hopes and dreams",
            "price"=>5.23)
        );

        /* print_r($cakes); */

        function cakeList($cakes) {
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach($cakes as $value) {

        if( is_array($value)) cakeList($value);

        else echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';

        }

        echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo cakeList($cakes);

        ?>
```

They want me to produce a list within html, to display the data within the comments. Any ideas? Or advice you guys at Stack overflow can show me how this does and ways to make it better?

Comment: I don't really see any difficulties, but may be `loads of methods` is a little too specific. Could you try to explain even less what you have tried and where you are stuck ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

`foreach($someArray as $key => $value)`

will allow you to get the keys of an array as well as the value.

Also entries in an array can be grabbed using the following syntax:

```
$a = array("foo"=>"Bar");
echo "The value at foo is ".$a['foo'];
```

The attempt you have can be updated with the above to get the result you need (remember you already know that `$value` is an array in your example).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to sort the list on price, i recommend using http://php.net/usort for this.
After you have sorted out the sorting, you can basically loop over the results to print them

```
function cakeList ($cakes)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($cakes as $cake => $details)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $cake . '<br/>' . $details['flavour'] . '<li/>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```